# Property 'setupInterceptor' does not exist on type 'BrowserObject'

Tags: webdriver-io

I am trying to use wdio intercept service ( https://webdriver.io/docs/wdio-intercept-service.html ) . I have installed yarn add wdio-intercept-service -D and npm i webdriverajax -D as well.

Usign browser.setupInterceptor() is throwing the error: Property 'setupInterceptor' does not exist on type 'BrowserObject'.

Answer (score 1):

Add `wdio-intercept-service` in your `tsconfig.json`'s *types* section